# how to reduce file size after bundling with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new using webpack and after bundling with it my file size is more than `500kb` just having the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
return(
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('main') );
```

It is not normal size I can tell. My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/bundled',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/bundled/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Is there anything I am missing which leading to this bigger file size?

Comment: This is too broad of a question as it is. However, one starting place would be to add some kind of minifier or uglifier to the resulting code.

Comment: Your build file contains at least react and babel-polyfill. React is ~250kb, babel-polyfill is ~100kb. All the es2015 boilerplate adds up for the rest. This is normal. A minifier/uglifier will bring this down by maybe 30% and gziping it over HTTP is going to bring it down to maybe 20% of the original size.